# ¿ Como poner un logo en la barra de navegación?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Hola estoy creando mi sitio web con la ayuda de todos y trato de poner un logo en la parte izquierda de la barra de navegaciòn, pero hasta ahora solo conseguí un ejemplo que me hace enorme la barra de navegación.

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
<img id="logo" src="images/logo-1.png" >
</a>
```

No se como ponerle con estos estilos que escogí y ustedes me ayudaron a mejorarlos.

Gracias.

```css
html,body{
  margin: 0; /* NUEVO */
}

/* NUEVA CLASE */
nav.navbar-default.negro{
  background-color: black;
  border-color: black;
}

body {
 background: #2f3133 url(../images/patternbg.jpg) 0 0 repeat;
}
/*----------- Back to top --------------*/
#toTop {
 display: none;
 width: 27px;
 height: 19px;
 overflow: hidden;
 background: url(../images/totop.png) 0 bottom no-repeat;
 position: fixed;
 margin-right: -690px !important;
 right: 50%;
 bottom: 60px;
 z-index: 999;
}
#toTop:hover {
 background-position: 0 0;
}
#toTop:active, #toTop:focus {
 outline: none;
}
/*-----------row_s--------------*/
.row_1 {
 text-align: center;
 padding: 30px 0;
 background: #2f3133 url(../images/patternbg.jpg) 0 0 repeat;
}
.row_2 {
 text-align: center;
 padding: 22px 0 0;
 background: #2f3133 url(../images/patternbg.jpg) 0 0 repeat;
}
.row_3 {
 padding: 43px 0 13px;
 background: url(../images/pattern2.jpg) 0 0 repeat;
}
.row_4 {
 padding: 30px 0 81px;
 background: #ffffff;
}
.row_5 {
 padding: 30px 0 98px;
 background: #ffffff;
}
.row_6 {
 padding: 30px 0 72px;
 background: #ffffff;
}
.row_7 {
 padding: 30px 0 80px;
 background: #ffffff;
}
.row_8 {
 padding: 63px 0 112px;
 background: #ffffff;
}
.row_9 {
 padding: 31px 0 90px;
 background: #ffffff;
}
.row_10 {
 padding: 101px 0 85px;
 background: #ffffff;
}
.row_11 {
 padding: 40px 0 40px;
 background: #ffffff;
}
/*------------links headings-----------*/
p {
 font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
 font-size: 15px;
 line-height: 22px;
 color: #adadad;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 margin-bottom: 11px;
}
h2 {
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 26px;
 line-height: 28px;
 color: #474848;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 35px 0;
}
h3 {
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 12px;
 line-height: 20px;
 color: #4e4134;
 margin: 0 0 10px;
 padding: 0;
}
.btn1 {
 position: relative;
 background: #545658;
 color: #ffffff;
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 15px;
 line-height: 22px;
 font-weight: normal;
 border-radius: 50px;
 border: none;
 padding: 20px 0 24px;
 margin: 0;
 width: 65px;
 height: 65px;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
 transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
.btn1:hover {
 text-decoration: none;
 background: #ffffff;
 color: #545658;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
 transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
.btn-link1 {
 position: relative;
 color: #585858;
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 15px;
 line-height: 22px;
 font-weight: normal;
}
.btn-link1 span {
 margin: 0 0 0 7px;
 top: 1px;
 position: relative;
 height: 11px;
 width: 11px;
 background: url(../images/arrowsmall1.png) center top no-repeat;
 display: inline-block;
}
.btn-link1:hover {
 color: #585858;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.btn-link1:hover span {
 background: url(../images/arrowsmall1.png) center bottom no-repeat;
}
.btn-link2 {
 position: relative;
 color: #eb5368;
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 15px;
 line-height: 22px;
 font-weight: normal;
}
.btn-link2 span {
 margin: 0 0 0 7px;
 top: 1px;
 position: relative;
 height: 11px;
 width: 11px;
 background: url(../images/arrowsmall1.png) center bottom no-repeat;
 display: inline-block;
}
.btn-link2:hover {
 color: #adadad;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.btn-link2:hover span {
 background: url(../images/arrowsmall1.png) center top no-repeat;
}
.btn-link2:focus {
 color: #adadad;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.btn-link3 {
 position: relative;
 color: #eb5368;
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 18px;
 line-height: 22px;
 font-weight: normal;
}
.btn-link3 span {
 top: 1px;
 margin: 0 11px 0 0;
 position: relative;
 height: 19px;
 width: 22px;
 background: url(../images/iconmail.png) center bottom no-repeat;
 display: inline-block;
}
.btn-link3:hover {
 color: #37383a;
 text-decoration: none;
}
/*------ header ------- */
header {
 background: #2f3133 url(../images/patternbg.jpg) 0 0 repeat;
 text-align: center;
}
/*-------- Logo -------- */
.navbar-brand_ {
 float: none;
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 margin: 0;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 68px auto 60px;
}
.navbar-brand_ img {
 max-width: 100%;
}
.navbar-brand_a:hover {
 text-decoration: none;
}
/*-----------------navbar---------------------*/
.menuheader {
 background: #545658;
}
.tm_navbar {
 /* position: relative; */  /* ELIMINADO */ 
 padding: 26px 0 22px;
 margin: 0;
 background: none;
 border: none;
}
.tm_navbar .nav {
 float: none;
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
}
.tm_navbar ul {
 position: relative;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 background: none;
 list-style: none;
}
.tm_navbar .nav li:first-child {
 position: relative;
 zoom: 1;
 background: none;
}
.tm_navbar .nav li {
 float: left;
 padding: 0 26px 0 27px;
 position: relative;
 zoom: 1;
 background: url(../images/bullet1.png) no-repeat left center;
}
.tm_navbar .nav li a {
 text-decoration: none;
 text-transform: lowercase;
 color: #ffffff;
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 22px;
 line-height: 24px;
 font-weight: normal;
 background: transparent;
 padding: 0;
 border: none;
 border-radius: 0;
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #333639;
}
.tm_navbar .nav > li > a .sf-sub-indicator {
 background: url(../images/indicator.png) no-repeat 0 bottom;
 width: 7px;
 height: 4px;
 display: inline-block;
 top: 30px;
 right: 23px;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 5;
}
.tm_navbar .nav li a:hover, .tm_navbar .nav > li.active > a, .tm_navbar .nav > li.active > a:hover {
 color: #ffcbd2;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.tm_navbar .nav > .active > a, .tm_navbar .nav > .active > a:hover, .tm_navbar .nav > .active > a:focus {
 color: #ffcbd2;
 background: transparent;
}
.tm_navbar .nav > li.sfHover.active > a .sf-sub-indicator, .tm_navbar .nav > li.active > a .sf-sub-indicator {
 background-position: 0 0;
}
.tm_navbar .nav > li.sfHover > a, .tm_navbar .nav > li.sfHover > a:hover, .tm_navbar .nav > li > a:hover, .tm_navbar .nav > li.active > a, .tm_navbar .nav > li.active > a:hover {
 color: #ffcbd2;
 background: transparent;
}
/*---------submenu1-------------*/
.tm_navbar .nav ul {
 position: absolute;
 display: none;
 top: 51px;
 left: 0px;
 width: 110px;
 padding: 20px 24px 10px;
 list-style: none;
 zoom: 1;
 z-index: 11;
 background: #eb5368;
 margin: 0;
 text-align: center;
}
.tm_navbar .nav ul li:first-child {
 width: 64px;
 padding: 0 0 6px;
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 zoom: 1;
 z-index: 10;
 background: transparent;
}
.tm_navbar .nav ul li:first-child img {
 position: absolute;
 top: -20px;
}
.tm_navbar .nav ul li {
 text-align: left;
 width: 64px;
 padding: 6px 0;
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 zoom: 1;
 z-index: 10;
 background: url(../images/dotted1.png) top center repeat-x;
}
.tm_navbar .nav ul li a {
 text-align: left;
 position: relative;
 color: #ffffff;
 padding: 0;
 font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
 font-size: 14px;
 line-height: 20px;
 font-weight: normal;
 margin: 0 0 0 10px;
 text-shadow: none;
}
.tm_navbar .nav ul li a:hover {
 color: #474848;
}
.tm_navbar .nav > li > ul li > a:hover, .tm_navbar .nav > li > ul li.sfHover > a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #474848;
}
.tm_navbar .nav > li > ul li > a:hover, .tm_navbar .nav > li > ul ul li.sfHover > a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #474848;
}
/*-----------submenu2-----------*/
.tm_navbar .nav ul ul {
 list-style: none;
 width: 87px;
 padding: 10px;
 background: #4e4134;
 left: 86px;
 top: 0px;
 background: url(../images/patternsubmenu2.jpg);
}
.tm_navbar .nav ul ul li:first-child {
 text-align: left;
 padding: 6px 0;
 position: relative;
 zoom: 1;
 z-index: 11;
 background: transparent;
}
.tm_navbar .nav ul ul li {
 text-align: left;
 padding: 6px 0;
 position: relative;
 zoom: 1;
 z-index: 11;
 background: url(../images/dotted2.png) top center repeat-x;
}
.tm_navbar .nav ul ul li a {
 color: #eb5368;
 text-shadow: none;
}
.tm_navbar .nav ul ul li a:hover {
 color: #474848;
}
/*-----indicator2-------*/
.tm_navbar .nav ul .sf-sub-indicator {
 background: url(../images/indicator.png) no-repeat 0 0;
 width: 7px;
 height: 5px;
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
 top: 8px;
 left: auto;
 right: -14px;
 z-index: 5;
}
/*-------------------select------------------*/
.select-menu {
 display: none !important;
}
/*--- header end ------*/
/*------ content ------- */
.title1 {
 color: #ffffff;
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 36px;
 line-height: 38px;
 font-weight: normal;
 margin-bottom: 24px;
}
.title2 {
 letter-spacing: 0;
 color: #939598;
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 17px;
 line-height: 26px;
 font-weight: normal;
 margin-bottom: 28px;
}
/*--------row2--------*/
.list1 {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 position: relative;
 list-style: none;
 overflow: hidden;
}
.list1 li a {
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 padding: 0;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
 transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
.list1 li a p {
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #c1c1c1;
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 30px;
 line-height: 32px;
 font-weight: normal;
 padding: 44px 0 41px;
 margin-bottom: 0;
}
.list1 li a:hover {
 text-decoration: none;
}
.list1 li a:hover p {
 color: #4e4134;
 text-decoration: none;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
 transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
.box1 {
 background: #eb5368;
}
.box1 figure {
 width: 100%;
}
.box1 figure img {
 width: 100%;
}
.box1 p {
 color: #ffffff;
}
.box2 {
 background: #f1d154;
}
.box2 figure {
 width: 100%;
}
.box2 figure img {
 width: 100%;
 height: 216px;
}
.box2 p {
 color: #ffffff;
}
.box3 {
 background: #5bb4d6;
}
.box3 figure {
 width: 100%;
}
.box3 figure img {
 width: 100%;
}
.box3 p {
 color: #ffffff;
}
.listbox1 {
 padding-right: 0;
}
.listbox2 {
 padding-right: 0;
 padding-left: 0;
}
.listbox3 {
 padding-left: 0;
}
/*---------list3-------------*/
.list3 {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 position: relative;
 list-style: none;
 overflow: hidden;
}
.box4 {
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
 background: #ffffff;
 margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.list3 li figure {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 float: left;
 overflow: hidden;
 display: block;
 margin-right: 20px;
}
.list3 li figure img {
 width: 100%;
}
.list3 li .info1 {
 overflow: hidden;
 margin-top: 30px;
 padding-right: 10px;
}
.list3title1 {
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 26px;
 line-height: 28px;
 font-weight: normal;
 color: #4e4134;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.list3title2 {
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 20px;
 line-height: 22px;
 font-weight: normal;
 color: #adadad;
 margin-bottom: 6px;
}
.list3title3 {
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 15px;
 line-height: 20px;
 font-weight: normal;
 color: #c6c6c6;
 margin-bottom: 8px;
}
/*------------chef------------*/
.title3 {
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 24px;
 line-height: 26px;
 font-weight: normal;
 color: #adadad;
 margin-bottom: 17px;
}
.chef figure {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 float: left;
 margin-right: 15px;
}
.chef figure img {
 width: 100%;
}
.chef .m_bot1 {
 margin-bottom: 14px;
}
/*--------list2--------*/
.list2 {
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
 margin: 6px 0 0 0;
 padding: 0;
}
.list2 li {
 overflow: hidden;
 list-style: none;
 padding: 0 0 0 23px;
 margin: 0 0 7px 0;
 background: url("../images/arrowsmal2.png") 0 5px no-repeat;
}
.list2 li:first-child {
 overflow: hidden;
 padding: 0 0 0 23px;
 margin: 0 0 8px 0;
}
.list2 > li {
 -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease;
 transition: all 0.1s ease;
}
.list2 > li > a {
 float: left;
 display: block;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 12px;
 line-height: 20px;
 font-weight: normal;
 color: #474848;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease;
 transition: all 0.1s ease;
}
.list2 > li > a:hover {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #eb5368;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease;
 transition: all 0.1s ease;
}
.locations .title4 {
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 19px;
 line-height: 26px;
 font-weight: normal;
 color: #adadad;
}
.locations figure {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 float: none;
 margin-bottom: 4px;
}
hr.line1 {
 outline: none;
 border: none;
 background: #e7decf;
 height: 1px;
 width: 100%;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 27px 0 33px;
}
.title5 {
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 19px;
 line-height: 26px;
 font-weight: normal;
 color: #797979;
 margin-bottom: 25px;
}
hr.line2 {
 outline: none;
 border: none;
 background: #dbdbdb;
 height: 1px;
 width: 100%;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 2px 0 27px;
}

.isotope, .isotope .isotope-item {
 -webkit-transition-duration: 0.8s;
 -moz-transition-duration: 0.8s;
 -ms-transition-duration: 0.8s;
 -o-transition-duration: 0.8s;
 transition-duration: 0.8s;
}
.isotope {
 -webkit-transition-property: height, width;
 -moz-transition-property: height, width;
 -ms-transition-property: height, width;
 -o-transition-property: height, width;
 transition-property: height, width;
}
.isotope .isotope-item {
 overflow: visible;
 -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform, opacity;
 -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform, opacity;
 -ms-transition-property: -ms-transform, opacity;
 -o-transition-property: top, left, opacity;
 transition-property: transform, opacity;
}
.isotope.no-transition, .isotope.no-transition .isotope-item, .isotope .isotope-item.no-transition {
 -webkit-transition-duration: 0s;
 -moz-transition-duration: 0s;
 -ms-transition-duration: 0s;
 -o-transition-duration: 0s;
 transition-duration: 0s;
}
.isotope.infinite-scrolling {
 -webkit-transition: none;
 -moz-transition: none;
 -ms-transition: none;
 -o-transition: none;
 transition: none;
}
.pad_bot3 {
 padding-bottom: 42px;
}
#container {
 margin-left: 0;
}
.containerExtra {
 margin-left: -30px;
}
.element {
 width: 270px;
 height: auto !important;
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 color: #222;
 border: none;
 margin: 0 !important;
 padding: 0 0 38px 30px;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
#filters.pagination li a.selected {
 color: #797979;
 background: none !important;
 border: none;
 text-decoration: underline;
}
#filters.pagination li {
 float: left;
}
#filters li {
 display: inline-block;
 margin-right: 26px !important;
}
#options {
 position: relative;
 margin-left: 0;
}
.element > a {
 margin: 0;
 display: block;
 position: relative;
}
.element > a figure {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 margin: 0 0 18px;
 padding: 0;
}
.element > a figure img {
 width: 100%;
}
.element > a span {
 position: relative;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 12px;
 line-height: 20px;
 color: #797979;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.element span {
 position: relative;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 12px;
 line-height: 20px;
 color: #797979;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.description {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
}
#filters {
 position: relative;
}
#filters li {
 display: inline-block;
 margin-right: 20px;
}
#filters li a {
 padding: 0;
 background: none;
 border: none;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 12px;
 line-height: 20px;
 color: #797979;
 margin: 0;
 text-decoration: none;
}
#filters li a:hover {
 background: none;
 border: none;
 text-decoration: none;
}
#options .pagination {
 margin: 1px 0 30px 0;
}
/*--------links------------*/
.btn-link4 {
 color: #474848;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease;
 transition: all 0.1s ease;
}
.btn-link4:hover {
 color: #eb5368;
 text-decoration: none;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease;
 transition: all 0.1s ease;
}
.pad_bot2 {
 padding-bottom: 43px;
}
.links p {
 margin-bottom: 28px;
}
.privacy_page h2 {
 padding-bottom: 42px;
}
.privacy_page p {
 margin-bottom: 22px;
}
.privacy_page .m_bot4 {
 margin-bottom: 27px;
}
.privacy_page a {
 color: #adadad;
}
.privacy_page a:hover {
 color: #eb5368;
}
.smalllogo2 {
 position: relative;
 top: 5px;
}
@media (min-width: 1220px) {
.chef figure {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 float: left;
 margin-right: 31px;
}
.list3 li figure {
 margin-right: 53px;
}
.list3 li .info1 {
 overflow: hidden;
 margin-top: 46px;
}
.box2 figure img {
 height: 270px;
}
.container {
 padding: 0;
}
}
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {

.box1,  .box2,  .box3 {
 float: none;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto 25px;
}
.box1 figure,  .box2 figure,  .box3 figure {
 width: 100%;
}
.box1 figure img,  .box2 figure img,  .box3 figure img {
 width: 100%;
}
.box2 figure img {
 height: auto;
}
.listbox1 {
 padding-right: 15px;
}
.listbox2 {
 padding-right: 15px;
 padding-left: 15px;
}
.listbox3 {
 padding-left: 15px;
}
.list1 {
 text-align: center;
}
.sf-menu {
 display: none !important;
}
.select-menu {
 display: block !important;
 color: #ffffff;
 border: 1px solid #343434;
 background: #343434 !important;
 -webkit-box-shadow: none;
 box-shadow: none;
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 5px;
}
.select-menu option {
 padding: 0;
}
}
/**************************************************/

@media (max-width: 480px) {
.list3 li figure {
 float: none;
 width: 100%;
 margin-right: 0;
}
.list3 li .info1 {
 padding: 20px;
 overflow: hidden;
 margin-top: 20px;
}
}
@media (max-width: 360px) {
.chef figure {
 padding: 0;
 float: none;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<header id="header">
      <div class="menuheader">
          <div class="container">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top tm_navbar negro" role="navigation">
                <ul class="nav sf-menu">
                  <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Casa</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="index.html">Sobre mi</a></li>
                  <li><a href="index-2.html">Guisos</a></li>
                  <li><a target="_blank" href="#">Postres</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
          </div>
      </div>
</header>
<div id="content">
    <div class="slider">
        <div class="camera_wrap">
          <div data-src="http://i64.tinypic.com/2qdmuis.jpg"></div>
          <div data-src="http://i64.tinypic.com/2qdmuis.jpg"></div>
          <div data-src="http://i64.tinypic.com/2qdmuis.jpg"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row_1">
        <div class="container">
            <p class="title1">Aprendamos a cocinar</p>
            <p class="title2">Sencillamente.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row_2">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <ul class="list1">
                    <li class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 listbox1">
                        <div class="box1">
                            <a href="#">
                                <figure><img src="http://i64.tinypic.com/2qdmuis.jpg" alt=""></figure>
                                <p>Guisos</p>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 listbox2">
                        <div class="box2">
                            <a href="galeri_vallas.html">
                                <p>VAsado</p>
                                <figure><img src="images/vallas_img/vallas9.jpg" height="500 px" alt=""></figure>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 listbox3">
                        <div class="box3">
                            <a href="galeri_podas.html">
                                <figure><img src="http://i64.tinypic.com/2qdmuis.jpg"  alt=""></figure>
                                <p>Postres</p>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row_3">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <ul class="list3">
                    <li class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                        <div class="box4">
                            <figure><img src="images/forestal_img/fores13.jpg" alt=""></figure>
                            <div class="info1 maxheight">
                                <p class="list3title1">Guiso</p>                                  
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                        <div class="box4">
                            <figure><img src="http://i64.tinypic.com/2qdmuis.jpg" alt=""></figure>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                        <div class="box4">
                            <figure><img src="http://i64.tinypic.com/2qdmuis.jpg" alt=""></figure>
                    </li>
                    <li class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                        <div class="box4">
                            <figure><img src="http://i64.tinypic.com/2qdmuis.jpg" alt=""></figure>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Probaste a aplicarle estilos CSS a la imagen para cambiar su height y width?

Comment: No hace falta que añades la clase `navbar-brand`, la cual te va a agregar estilos innecesarios. Simplemente agrega la imagen con el link dentro del `nav` pero antes de las opciones del menú y listo. Posiblemente tendrás que indicarle un tamaño a tu imagen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intenta esto:

**Primero** vamos borrar la clase **navbar-brand** y agregamos otra como **navbar-logo** o la que desees. Yo la voy a agregar por fuera del menú, así:

```
<nav class="navbar (etc)">
    <a class="navbar-logo" href="#">
      <img src="images/logo-1.png" >
    </a>
    <ul class="nav sf-menu">
       <!--otros li-->
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**Segundo:** En el css, agregamos esta misma clase (En este ejemplo, la voy a agregar arriba, pero lo ideal es que vaya en el orden que es), una vez allí, indicamos que va a tener un comportamiento de **bloque en línea** y una **alineación vertical** al medio, luego por supuesto el ancho del logo.

```
.navbar-logo{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 70px;
}
```

**Tercero:** A la imagen `<img src="logo.png"/>` vamos agregarle un comportamiento de tipo **bloque**, un ancho del 100% igual al contenedor padre y una altura automática, según la dimensión/proporción de la imagen. Así:

```
.navbar-logo img{
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

De resto, sería jugar con los estilos según quieras, por ejemplo, voy a tomar una imagen de internet y vamos a probar con tu código:

```css
html,body{
  margin: 0; /* NUEVO */
}

/* NUEVA CLASE */
nav.navbar-default.negro{
  background-color: black;
  border-color: black;
}

.logo{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 6em; /*El tamaño en que desees*/
  filter: brightness(100); /*<-- Este ignoralo, lo puse porque la imagen no resaltaba sobre fondo negro*/ 
  margin: -.5em auto; /*<-- Este es para cancelar el espacio entre la barra de navegación y la imagen*/
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.logo img{
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

body {
 background: #2f3133 url(../images/patternbg.jpg) 0 0 repeat;
}
/*----------- Back to top --------------*/
#toTop {
 display: none;
 width: 27px;
 height: 19px;
 overflow: hidden;
 background: url(../images/totop.png) 0 bottom no-repeat;
 position: fixed;
 margin-right: -690px !important;
 right: 50%;
 bottom: 60px;
 z-index: 999;
}
#toTop:hover {
 background-position: 0 0;
}
#toTop:active, #toTop:focus {
 outline: none;
}
/*-----------row_s--------------*/
.row_1 {
 text-align: center;
 padding: 30px 0;
 background: #2f3133 url(../images/patternbg.jpg) 0 0 repeat;
}
.row_2 {
 text-align: center;
 padding: 22px 0 0;
 background: #2f3133 url(../images/patternbg.jpg) 0 0 repeat;
}
.row_3 {
 padding: 43px 0 13px;
 background: url(../images/pattern2.jpg) 0 0 repeat;
}
.row_4 {
 padding: 30px 0 81px;
 background: #ffffff;
}
.row_5 {
 padding: 30px 0 98px;
 background: #ffffff;
}
.row_6 {
 padding: 30px 0 72px;
 background: #ffffff;
}
.row_7 {
 padding: 30px 0 80px;
 background: #ffffff;
}
.row_8 {
 padding: 63px 0 112px;
 background: #ffffff;
}
.row_9 {
 padding: 31px 0 90px;
 background: #ffffff;
}
.row_10 {
 padding: 101px 0 85px;
 background: #ffffff;
}
.row_11 {
 padding: 40px 0 40px;
 background: #ffffff;
}
/*------------links headings-----------*/
p {
 font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
 font-size: 15px;
 line-height: 22px;
 color: #adadad;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 margin-bottom: 11px;
}
h2 {
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 26px;
 line-height: 28px;
 color: #474848;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 35px 0;
}
h3 {
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 12px;
 line-height: 20px;
 color: #4e4134;
 margin: 0 0 10px;
 padding: 0;
}
.btn1 {
 position: relative;
 background: #545658;
 color: #ffffff;
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 15px;
 line-height: 22px;
 font-weight: normal;
 border-radius: 50px;
 border: none;
 padding: 20px 0 24px;
 margin: 0;
 width: 65px;
 height: 65px;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
 transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
.btn1:hover {
 text-decoration: none;
 background: #ffffff;
 color: #545658;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
 transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
.btn-link1 {
 position: relative;
 color: #585858;
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 15px;
 line-height: 22px;
 font-weight: normal;
}
.btn-link1 span {
 margin: 0 0 0 7px;
 top: 1px;
 position: relative;
 height: 11px;
 width: 11px;
 background: url(../images/arrowsmall1.png) center top no-repeat;
 display: inline-block;
}
.btn-link1:hover {
 color: #585858;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.btn-link1:hover span {
 background: url(../images/arrowsmall1.png) center bottom no-repeat;
}
.btn-link2 {
 position: relative;
 color: #eb5368;
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 15px;
 line-height: 22px;
 font-weight: normal;
}
.btn-link2 span {
 margin: 0 0 0 7px;
 top: 1px;
 position: relative;
 height: 11px;
 width: 11px;
 background: url(../images/arrowsmall1.png) center bottom no-repeat;
 display: inline-block;
}
.btn-link2:hover {
 color: #adadad;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.btn-link2:hover span {
 background: url(../images/arrowsmall1.png) center top no-repeat;
}
.btn-link2:focus {
 color: #adadad;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.btn-link3 {
 position: relative;
 color: #eb5368;
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 18px;
 line-height: 22px;
 font-weight: normal;
}
.btn-link3 span {
 top: 1px;
 margin: 0 11px 0 0;
 position: relative;
 height: 19px;
 width: 22px;
 background: url(../images/iconmail.png) center bottom no-repeat;
 display: inline-block;
}
.btn-link3:hover {
 color: #37383a;
 text-decoration: none;
}
/*------ header ------- */
header {
 background: #2f3133 url(../images/patternbg.jpg) 0 0 repeat;
 text-align: center;
}
/*-------- Logo -------- */
.navbar-brand_ {
 float: none;
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 margin: 0;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 68px auto 60px;
}
.navbar-brand_ img {
 max-width: 100%;
}
.navbar-brand_a:hover {
 text-decoration: none;
}
/*-----------------navbar---------------------*/
.menuheader {
 background: #545658;
}
.tm_navbar {
 /* position: relative; */  /* ELIMINADO */ 
 padding: 26px 0 22px;
 margin: 0;
 background: none;
 border: none;
}
.tm_navbar .nav {
 float: none;
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
}
.tm_navbar ul {
 position: relative;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 background: none;
 list-style: none;
}
.tm_navbar .nav li:first-child {
 position: relative;
 zoom: 1;
 background: none;
}
.tm_navbar .nav li {
 float: left;
 padding: 0 26px 0 27px;
 position: relative;
 zoom: 1;
 background: url(../images/bullet1.png) no-repeat left center;
}
.tm_navbar .nav li a {
 text-decoration: none;
 text-transform: lowercase;
 color: #ffffff;
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 22px;
 line-height: 24px;
 font-weight: normal;
 background: transparent;
 padding: 0;
 border: none;
 border-radius: 0;
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #333639;
}
.tm_navbar .nav > li > a .sf-sub-indicator {
 background: url(../images/indicator.png) no-repeat 0 bottom;
 width: 7px;
 height: 4px;
 display: inline-block;
 top: 30px;
 right: 23px;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 5;
}
.tm_navbar .nav li a:hover, .tm_navbar .nav > li.active > a, .tm_navbar .nav > li.active > a:hover {
 color: #ffcbd2;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.tm_navbar .nav > .active > a, .tm_navbar .nav > .active > a:hover, .tm_navbar .nav > .active > a:focus {
 color: #ffcbd2;
 background: transparent;
}
.tm_navbar .nav > li.sfHover.active > a .sf-sub-indicator, .tm_navbar .nav > li.active > a .sf-sub-indicator {
 background-position: 0 0;
}
.tm_navbar .nav > li.sfHover > a, .tm_navbar .nav > li.sfHover > a:hover, .tm_navbar .nav > li > a:hover, .tm_navbar .nav > li.active > a, .tm_navbar .nav > li.active > a:hover {
 color: #ffcbd2;
 background: transparent;
}
/*---------submenu1-------------*/
.tm_navbar .nav ul {
 position: absolute;
 display: none;
 top: 51px;
 left: 0px;
 width: 110px;
 padding: 20px 24px 10px;
 list-style: none;
 zoom: 1;
 z-index: 11;
 background: #eb5368;
 margin: 0;
 text-align: center;
}
.tm_navbar .nav ul li:first-child {
 width: 64px;
 padding: 0 0 6px;
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 zoom: 1;
 z-index: 10;
 background: transparent;
}
.tm_navbar .nav ul li:first-child img {
 position: absolute;
 top: -20px;
}
.tm_navbar .nav ul li {
 text-align: left;
 width: 64px;
 padding: 6px 0;
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 zoom: 1;
 z-index: 10;
 background: url(../images/dotted1.png) top center repeat-x;
}
.tm_navbar .nav ul li a {
 text-align: left;
 position: relative;
 color: #ffffff;
 padding: 0;
 font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
 font-size: 14px;
 line-height: 20px;
 font-weight: normal;
 margin: 0 0 0 10px;
 text-shadow: none;
}
.tm_navbar .nav ul li a:hover {
 color: #474848;
}
.tm_navbar .nav > li > ul li > a:hover, .tm_navbar .nav > li > ul li.sfHover > a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #474848;
}
.tm_navbar .nav > li > ul li > a:hover, .tm_navbar .nav > li > ul ul li.sfHover > a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #474848;
}
/*-----------submenu2-----------*/
.tm_navbar .nav ul ul {
 list-style: none;
 width: 87px;
 padding: 10px;
 background: #4e4134;
 left: 86px;
 top: 0px;
 background: url(../images/patternsubmenu2.jpg);
}
.tm_navbar .nav ul ul li:first-child {
 text-align: left;
 padding: 6px 0;
 position: relative;
 zoom: 1;
 z-index: 11;
 background: transparent;
}
.tm_navbar .nav ul ul li {
 text-align: left;
 padding: 6px 0;
 position: relative;
 zoom: 1;
 z-index: 11;
 background: url(../images/dotted2.png) top center repeat-x;
}
.tm_navbar .nav ul ul li a {
 color: #eb5368;
 text-shadow: none;
}
.tm_navbar .nav ul ul li a:hover {
 color: #474848;
}
/*-----indicator2-------*/
.tm_navbar .nav ul .sf-sub-indicator {
 background: url(../images/indicator.png) no-repeat 0 0;
 width: 7px;
 height: 5px;
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
 top: 8px;
 left: auto;
 right: -14px;
 z-index: 5;
}
/*-------------------select------------------*/
.select-menu {
 display: none !important;
}
/*--- header end ------*/
/*------ content ------- */
.title1 {
 color: #ffffff;
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 36px;
 line-height: 38px;
 font-weight: normal;
 margin-bottom: 24px;
}
.title2 {
 letter-spacing: 0;
 color: #939598;
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 17px;
 line-height: 26px;
 font-weight: normal;
 margin-bottom: 28px;
}
/*--------row2--------*/
.list1 {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 position: relative;
 list-style: none;
 overflow: hidden;
}
.list1 li a {
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 padding: 0;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
 transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
.list1 li a p {
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #c1c1c1;
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 30px;
 line-height: 32px;
 font-weight: normal;
 padding: 44px 0 41px;
 margin-bottom: 0;
}
.list1 li a:hover {
 text-decoration: none;
}
.list1 li a:hover p {
 color: #4e4134;
 text-decoration: none;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
 transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
.box1 {
 background: #eb5368;
}
.box1 figure {
 width: 100%;
}
.box1 figure img {
 width: 100%;
}
.box1 p {
 color: #ffffff;
}
.box2 {
 background: #f1d154;
}
.box2 figure {
 width: 100%;
}
.box2 figure img {
 width: 100%;
 height: 216px;
}
.box2 p {
 color: #ffffff;
}
.box3 {
 background: #5bb4d6;
}
.box3 figure {
 width: 100%;
}
.box3 figure img {
 width: 100%;
}
.box3 p {
 color: #ffffff;
}
.listbox1 {
 padding-right: 0;
}
.listbox2 {
 padding-right: 0;
 padding-left: 0;
}
.listbox3 {
 padding-left: 0;
}
/*---------list3-------------*/
.list3 {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 position: relative;
 list-style: none;
 overflow: hidden;
}
.box4 {
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
 background: #ffffff;
 margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.list3 li figure {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 float: left;
 overflow: hidden;
 display: block;
 margin-right: 20px;
}
.list3 li figure img {
 width: 100%;
}
.list3 li .info1 {
 overflow: hidden;
 margin-top: 30px;
 padding-right: 10px;
}
.list3title1 {
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 26px;
 line-height: 28px;
 font-weight: normal;
 color: #4e4134;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.list3title2 {
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 20px;
 line-height: 22px;
 font-weight: normal;
 color: #adadad;
 margin-bottom: 6px;
}
.list3title3 {
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 15px;
 line-height: 20px;
 font-weight: normal;
 color: #c6c6c6;
 margin-bottom: 8px;
}
/*------------chef------------*/
.title3 {
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 24px;
 line-height: 26px;
 font-weight: normal;
 color: #adadad;
 margin-bottom: 17px;
}
.chef figure {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 float: left;
 margin-right: 15px;
}
.chef figure img {
 width: 100%;
}
.chef .m_bot1 {
 margin-bottom: 14px;
}
/*--------list2--------*/
.list2 {
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
 margin: 6px 0 0 0;
 padding: 0;
}
.list2 li {
 overflow: hidden;
 list-style: none;
 padding: 0 0 0 23px;
 margin: 0 0 7px 0;
 background: url("../images/arrowsmal2.png") 0 5px no-repeat;
}
.list2 li:first-child {
 overflow: hidden;
 padding: 0 0 0 23px;
 margin: 0 0 8px 0;
}
.list2 > li {
 -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease;
 transition: all 0.1s ease;
}
.list2 > li > a {
 float: left;
 display: block;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 12px;
 line-height: 20px;
 font-weight: normal;
 color: #474848;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease;
 transition: all 0.1s ease;
}
.list2 > li > a:hover {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #eb5368;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease;
 transition: all 0.1s ease;
}
.locations .title4 {
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 19px;
 line-height: 26px;
 font-weight: normal;
 color: #adadad;
}
.locations figure {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 float: none;
 margin-bottom: 4px;
}
hr.line1 {
 outline: none;
 border: none;
 background: #e7decf;
 height: 1px;
 width: 100%;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 27px 0 33px;
}
.title5 {
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 19px;
 line-height: 26px;
 font-weight: normal;
 color: #797979;
 margin-bottom: 25px;
}
hr.line2 {
 outline: none;
 border: none;
 background: #dbdbdb;
 height: 1px;
 width: 100%;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 2px 0 27px;
}

.isotope, .isotope .isotope-item {
 -webkit-transition-duration: 0.8s;
 -moz-transition-duration: 0.8s;
 -ms-transition-duration: 0.8s;
 -o-transition-duration: 0.8s;
 transition-duration: 0.8s;
}
.isotope {
 -webkit-transition-property: height, width;
 -moz-transition-property: height, width;
 -ms-transition-property: height, width;
 -o-transition-property: height, width;
 transition-property: height, width;
}
.isotope .isotope-item {
 overflow: visible;
 -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform, opacity;
 -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform, opacity;
 -ms-transition-property: -ms-transform, opacity;
 -o-transition-property: top, left, opacity;
 transition-property: transform, opacity;
}
.isotope.no-transition, .isotope.no-transition .isotope-item, .isotope .isotope-item.no-transition {
 -webkit-transition-duration: 0s;
 -moz-transition-duration: 0s;
 -ms-transition-duration: 0s;
 -o-transition-duration: 0s;
 transition-duration: 0s;
}
.isotope.infinite-scrolling {
 -webkit-transition: none;
 -moz-transition: none;
 -ms-transition: none;
 -o-transition: none;
 transition: none;
}
.pad_bot3 {
 padding-bottom: 42px;
}
#container {
 margin-left: 0;
}
.containerExtra {
 margin-left: -30px;
}
.element {
 width: 270px;
 height: auto !important;
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 color: #222;
 border: none;
 margin: 0 !important;
 padding: 0 0 38px 30px;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
#filters.pagination li a.selected {
 color: #797979;
 background: none !important;
 border: none;
 text-decoration: underline;
}
#filters.pagination li {
 float: left;
}
#filters li {
 display: inline-block;
 margin-right: 26px !important;
}
#options {
 position: relative;
 margin-left: 0;
}
.element > a {
 margin: 0;
 display: block;
 position: relative;
}
.element > a figure {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 margin: 0 0 18px;
 padding: 0;
}
.element > a figure img {
 width: 100%;
}
.element > a span {
 position: relative;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 12px;
 line-height: 20px;
 color: #797979;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.element span {
 position: relative;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 12px;
 line-height: 20px;
 color: #797979;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.description {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
}
#filters {
 position: relative;
}
#filters li {
 display: inline-block;
 margin-right: 20px;
}
#filters li a {
 padding: 0;
 background: none;
 border: none;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 12px;
 line-height: 20px;
 color: #797979;
 margin: 0;
 text-decoration: none;
}
#filters li a:hover {
 background: none;
 border: none;
 text-decoration: none;
}
#options .pagination {
 margin: 1px 0 30px 0;
}
/*--------links------------*/
.btn-link4 {
 color: #474848;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease;
 transition: all 0.1s ease;
}
.btn-link4:hover {
 color: #eb5368;
 text-decoration: none;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease;
 transition: all 0.1s ease;
}
.pad_bot2 {
 padding-bottom: 43px;
}
.links p {
 margin-bottom: 28px;
}
.privacy_page h2 {
 padding-bottom: 42px;
}
.privacy_page p {
 margin-bottom: 22px;
}
.privacy_page .m_bot4 {
 margin-bottom: 27px;
}
.privacy_page a {
 color: #adadad;
}
.privacy_page a:hover {
 color: #eb5368;
}
.smalllogo2 {
 position: relative;
 top: 5px;
}
@media (min-width: 1220px) {
.chef figure {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 float: left;
 margin-right: 31px;
}
.list3 li figure {
 margin-right: 53px;
}
.list3 li .info1 {
 overflow: hidden;
 margin-top: 46px;
}
.box2 figure img {
 height: 270px;
}
.container {
 padding: 0;
}
}
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {

.box1,  .box2,  .box3 {
 float: none;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto 25px;
}
.box1 figure,  .box2 figure,  .box3 figure {
 width: 100%;
}
.box1 figure img,  .box2 figure img,  .box3 figure img {
 width: 100%;
}
.box2 figure img {
 height: auto;
}
.listbox1 {
 padding-right: 15px;
}
.listbox2 {
 padding-right: 15px;
 padding-left: 15px;
}
.listbox3 {
 padding-left: 15px;
}
.list1 {
 text-align: center;
}
.sf-menu {
 display: none !important;
}
.select-menu {
 display: block !important;
 color: #ffffff;
 border: 1px solid #343434;
 background: #343434 !important;
 -webkit-box-shadow: none;
 box-shadow: none;
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 5px;
}
.select-menu option {
 padding: 0;
}
}
/**************************************************/

@media (max-width: 480px) {
.list3 li figure {
 float: none;
 width: 100%;
 margin-right: 0;
}
.list3 li .info1 {
 padding: 20px;
 overflow: hidden;
 margin-top: 20px;
}
}
@media (max-width: 360px) {
.chef figure {
 padding: 0;
 float: none;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<header id="header">
      <div class="menuheader">
          <div class="container">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top tm_navbar negro" role="navigation">
                <a class="logo" href="">
                  <img src="https://co.foodmarketmaker.com/uploads/4732a5642a55c91741242bad4ac6e494.png"/>
                </a>
                <ul class="nav sf-menu">
                  <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Casa</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="index.html">Sobre mi</a></li>
                  <li><a href="index-2.html">Guisos</a></li>
                  <li><a target="_blank" href="#">Postres</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
          </div>
      </div>
</header>
<div id="content">
    <div class="slider">
        <div class="camera_wrap">
          <div data-src="http://i64.tinypic.com/2qdmuis.jpg"></div>
          <div data-src="http://i64.tinypic.com/2qdmuis.jpg"></div>
          <div data-src="http://i64.tinypic.com/2qdmuis.jpg"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row_1">
        <div class="container">
            <p class="title1">Aprendamos a cocinar</p>
            <p class="title2">Sencillamente.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row_2">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <ul class="list1">
                    <li class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 listbox1">
                        <div class="box1">
                            <a href="#">
                                <figure><img src="http://i64.tinypic.com/2qdmuis.jpg" alt=""></figure>
                                <p>Guisos</p>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 listbox2">
                        <div class="box2">
                            <a href="galeri_vallas.html">
                                <p>VAsado</p>
                                <figure><img src="images/vallas_img/vallas9.jpg" height="500 px" alt=""></figure>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 listbox3">
                        <div class="box3">
                            <a href="galeri_podas.html">
                                <figure><img src="http://i64.tinypic.com/2qdmuis.jpg"  alt=""></figure>
                                <p>Postres</p>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row_3">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <ul class="list3">
                    <li class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                        <div class="box4">
                            <figure><img src="images/forestal_img/fores13.jpg" alt=""></figure>
                            <div class="info1 maxheight">
                                <p class="list3title1">Guiso</p>                                  
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                        <div class="box4">
                            <figure><img src="http://i64.tinypic.com/2qdmuis.jpg" alt=""></figure>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                        <div class="box4">
                            <figure><img src="http://i64.tinypic.com/2qdmuis.jpg" alt=""></figure>
                    </li>
                    <li class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                        <div class="box4">
                            <figure><img src="http://i64.tinypic.com/2qdmuis.jpg" alt=""></figure>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Como ves use otra clase, simplemente "logo" porque como te comente, puedes usar la clase que quieras invertarte. Le ajuste el margin en negativo, porque el navbar tiene un padding que agrega un espacio y esta es una forma de contrarrestarlo, otra opción hubiese sido simplemente disminuir ese padding al navbar. Lo otro que puedes ignorar, son los filtros para la capa de ajustes, que use porque el logo que cogí de internet tenía las letras negras y en el fondo pues no se ve, otra opción hubiese sido poner el fondo del logo en blanco, pero quise hacerlo así.

Si aún no te funciona, me escribes en los comentario y ahi vemos. Éxitos!

### Actualización

Sí quieres quitar o disminuir el alto de la barra, intenta esto:

```
nav.tm_navbar.negro {
    padding: 0; /*o lo que necesites*/
    min-height: 25px; /*o lo que necesites*/
}
```

Comment: Gracias @Edgar Gutiérez , funciona a la perfección. Lo que si intente reducir el alto o padding de la barra sin éxito, pues es un poco ancha o tiene mucha altura. Pero seguiré buscando la manera. Muchas gracias de nuevo.

Comment: @gemita Hola, actualice mi respuesta, por lo de la reducción de la altura. Saludos!

Answer (score 3):

??? pues solo pon la imagen y ya...  o cual es problema?

Espero que te sirva el siguiente ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```css
html,body{
  margin: 0; /* NUEVO */
}

/* CSs para manejo del logo */
#logo{
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKw6X.png);
    width: 170px;
    height: 40px;
    top: -5px;
}

/* NUEVA CLASE */
nav.navbar-default.negro{
  background-color: black;
  border-color: black;
}

body {
 background: #2f3133 url(../images/patternbg.jpg) 0 0 repeat;
}
/*----------- Back to top --------------*/
#toTop {
 display: none;
 width: 27px;
 height: 19px;
 overflow: hidden;
 background: url(../images/totop.png) 0 bottom no-repeat;
 position: fixed;
 margin-right: -690px !important;
 right: 50%;
 bottom: 60px;
 z-index: 999;
}
#toTop:hover {
 background-position: 0 0;
}
#toTop:active, #toTop:focus {
 outline: none;
}
/*-----------row_s--------------*/
.row_1 {
 text-align: center;
 padding: 30px 0;
 background: #2f3133 url(../images/patternbg.jpg) 0 0 repeat;
}
.row_2 {
 text-align: center;
 padding: 22px 0 0;
 background: #2f3133 url(../images/patternbg.jpg) 0 0 repeat;
}
.row_3 {
 padding: 43px 0 13px;
 background: url(../images/pattern2.jpg) 0 0 repeat;
}
.row_4 {
 padding: 30px 0 81px;
 background: #ffffff;
}
.row_5 {
 padding: 30px 0 98px;
 background: #ffffff;
}
.row_6 {
 padding: 30px 0 72px;
 background: #ffffff;
}
.row_7 {
 padding: 30px 0 80px;
 background: #ffffff;
}
.row_8 {
 padding: 63px 0 112px;
 background: #ffffff;
}
.row_9 {
 padding: 31px 0 90px;
 background: #ffffff;
}
.row_10 {
 padding: 101px 0 85px;
 background: #ffffff;
}
.row_11 {
 padding: 40px 0 40px;
 background: #ffffff;
}
/*------------links headings-----------*/
p {
 font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
 font-size: 15px;
 line-height: 22px;
 color: #adadad;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 margin-bottom: 11px;
}
h2 {
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 26px;
 line-height: 28px;
 color: #474848;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 35px 0;
}
h3 {
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 12px;
 line-height: 20px;
 color: #4e4134;
 margin: 0 0 10px;
 padding: 0;
}
.btn1 {
 position: relative;
 background: #545658;
 color: #ffffff;
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 15px;
 line-height: 22px;
 font-weight: normal;
 border-radius: 50px;
 border: none;
 padding: 20px 0 24px;
 margin: 0;
 width: 65px;
 height: 65px;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
 transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
.btn1:hover {
 text-decoration: none;
 background: #ffffff;
 color: #545658;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
 transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
.btn-link1 {
 position: relative;
 color: #585858;
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 15px;
 line-height: 22px;
 font-weight: normal;
}
.btn-link1 span {
 margin: 0 0 0 7px;
 top: 1px;
 position: relative;
 height: 11px;
 width: 11px;
 background: url(../images/arrowsmall1.png) center top no-repeat;
 display: inline-block;
}
.btn-link1:hover {
 color: #585858;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.btn-link1:hover span {
 background: url(../images/arrowsmall1.png) center bottom no-repeat;
}
.btn-link2 {
 position: relative;
 color: #eb5368;
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 15px;
 line-height: 22px;
 font-weight: normal;
}
.btn-link2 span {
 margin: 0 0 0 7px;
 top: 1px;
 position: relative;
 height: 11px;
 width: 11px;
 background: url(../images/arrowsmall1.png) center bottom no-repeat;
 display: inline-block;
}
.btn-link2:hover {
 color: #adadad;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.btn-link2:hover span {
 background: url(../images/arrowsmall1.png) center top no-repeat;
}
.btn-link2:focus {
 color: #adadad;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.btn-link3 {
 position: relative;
 color: #eb5368;
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 18px;
 line-height: 22px;
 font-weight: normal;
}
.btn-link3 span {
 top: 1px;
 margin: 0 11px 0 0;
 position: relative;
 height: 19px;
 width: 22px;
 background: url(../images/iconmail.png) center bottom no-repeat;
 display: inline-block;
}
.btn-link3:hover {
 color: #37383a;
 text-decoration: none;
}
/*------ header ------- */
header {
 background: #2f3133 url(../images/patternbg.jpg) 0 0 repeat;
 text-align: center;
}
/*-------- Logo -------- */
.navbar-brand_ {
 float: none;
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 margin: 0;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 68px auto 60px;
}
.navbar-brand_ img {
 max-width: 100%;
}
.navbar-brand_a:hover {
 text-decoration: none;
}
/*-----------------navbar---------------------*/
.menuheader {
 background: #545658;
}
.tm_navbar {
 /* position: relative; */  /* ELIMINADO */ 
 padding: 26px 0 22px;
 margin: 0;
 background: none;
 border: none;
}
.tm_navbar .nav {
 float: none;
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
}
.tm_navbar ul {
 position: relative;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 background: none;
 list-style: none;
}
.tm_navbar .nav li:first-child {
 position: relative;
 zoom: 1;
 background: none;
}
.tm_navbar .nav li {
 float: left;
 padding: 0 26px 0 27px;
 position: relative;
 zoom: 1;
 background: url(../images/bullet1.png) no-repeat left center;
}
.tm_navbar .nav li a {
 text-decoration: none;
 text-transform: lowercase;
 color: #ffffff;
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 22px;
 line-height: 24px;
 font-weight: normal;
 background: transparent;
 padding: 0;
 border: none;
 border-radius: 0;
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #333639;
}
.tm_navbar .nav > li > a .sf-sub-indicator {
 background: url(../images/indicator.png) no-repeat 0 bottom;
 width: 7px;
 height: 4px;
 display: inline-block;
 top: 30px;
 right: 23px;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 5;
}
.tm_navbar .nav li a:hover, .tm_navbar .nav > li.active > a, .tm_navbar .nav > li.active > a:hover {
 color: #ffcbd2;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.tm_navbar .nav > .active > a, .tm_navbar .nav > .active > a:hover, .tm_navbar .nav > .active > a:focus {
 color: #ffcbd2;
 background: transparent;
}
.tm_navbar .nav > li.sfHover.active > a .sf-sub-indicator, .tm_navbar .nav > li.active > a .sf-sub-indicator {
 background-position: 0 0;
}
.tm_navbar .nav > li.sfHover > a, .tm_navbar .nav > li.sfHover > a:hover, .tm_navbar .nav > li > a:hover, .tm_navbar .nav > li.active > a, .tm_navbar .nav > li.active > a:hover {
 color: #ffcbd2;
 background: transparent;
}
/*---------submenu1-------------*/
.tm_navbar .nav ul {
 position: absolute;
 display: none;
 top: 51px;
 left: 0px;
 width: 110px;
 padding: 20px 24px 10px;
 list-style: none;
 zoom: 1;
 z-index: 11;
 background: #eb5368;
 margin: 0;
 text-align: center;
}
.tm_navbar .nav ul li:first-child {
 width: 64px;
 padding: 0 0 6px;
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 zoom: 1;
 z-index: 10;
 background: transparent;
}
.tm_navbar .nav ul li:first-child img {
 position: absolute;
 top: -20px;
}
.tm_navbar .nav ul li {
 text-align: left;
 width: 64px;
 padding: 6px 0;
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 zoom: 1;
 z-index: 10;
 background: url(../images/dotted1.png) top center repeat-x;
}
.tm_navbar .nav ul li a {
 text-align: left;
 position: relative;
 color: #ffffff;
 padding: 0;
 font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
 font-size: 14px;
 line-height: 20px;
 font-weight: normal;
 margin: 0 0 0 10px;
 text-shadow: none;
}
.tm_navbar .nav ul li a:hover {
 color: #474848;
}
.tm_navbar .nav > li > ul li > a:hover, .tm_navbar .nav > li > ul li.sfHover > a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #474848;
}
.tm_navbar .nav > li > ul li > a:hover, .tm_navbar .nav > li > ul ul li.sfHover > a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #474848;
}
/*-----------submenu2-----------*/
.tm_navbar .nav ul ul {
 list-style: none;
 width: 87px;
 padding: 10px;
 background: #4e4134;
 left: 86px;
 top: 0px;
 background: url(../images/patternsubmenu2.jpg);
}
.tm_navbar .nav ul ul li:first-child {
 text-align: left;
 padding: 6px 0;
 position: relative;
 zoom: 1;
 z-index: 11;
 background: transparent;
}
.tm_navbar .nav ul ul li {
 text-align: left;
 padding: 6px 0;
 position: relative;
 zoom: 1;
 z-index: 11;
 background: url(../images/dotted2.png) top center repeat-x;
}
.tm_navbar .nav ul ul li a {
 color: #eb5368;
 text-shadow: none;
}
.tm_navbar .nav ul ul li a:hover {
 color: #474848;
}
/*-----indicator2-------*/
.tm_navbar .nav ul .sf-sub-indicator {
 background: url(../images/indicator.png) no-repeat 0 0;
 width: 7px;
 height: 5px;
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
 top: 8px;
 left: auto;
 right: -14px;
 z-index: 5;
}
/*-------------------select------------------*/
.select-menu {
 display: none !important;
}
/*--- header end ------*/
/*------ content ------- */
.title1 {
 color: #ffffff;
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 36px;
 line-height: 38px;
 font-weight: normal;
 margin-bottom: 24px;
}
.title2 {
 letter-spacing: 0;
 color: #939598;
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 17px;
 line-height: 26px;
 font-weight: normal;
 margin-bottom: 28px;
}
/*--------row2--------*/
.list1 {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 position: relative;
 list-style: none;
 overflow: hidden;
}
.list1 li a {
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 padding: 0;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
 transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
.list1 li a p {
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #c1c1c1;
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 30px;
 line-height: 32px;
 font-weight: normal;
 padding: 44px 0 41px;
 margin-bottom: 0;
}
.list1 li a:hover {
 text-decoration: none;
}
.list1 li a:hover p {
 color: #4e4134;
 text-decoration: none;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
 transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
.box1 {
 background: #eb5368;
}
.box1 figure {
 width: 100%;
}
.box1 figure img {
 width: 100%;
}
.box1 p {
 color: #ffffff;
}
.box2 {
 background: #f1d154;
}
.box2 figure {
 width: 100%;
}
.box2 figure img {
 width: 100%;
 height: 216px;
}
.box2 p {
 color: #ffffff;
}
.box3 {
 background: #5bb4d6;
}
.box3 figure {
 width: 100%;
}
.box3 figure img {
 width: 100%;
}
.box3 p {
 color: #ffffff;
}
.listbox1 {
 padding-right: 0;
}
.listbox2 {
 padding-right: 0;
 padding-left: 0;
}
.listbox3 {
 padding-left: 0;
}
/*---------list3-------------*/
.list3 {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 position: relative;
 list-style: none;
 overflow: hidden;
}
.box4 {
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
 background: #ffffff;
 margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.list3 li figure {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 float: left;
 overflow: hidden;
 display: block;
 margin-right: 20px;
}
.list3 li figure img {
 width: 100%;
}
.list3 li .info1 {
 overflow: hidden;
 margin-top: 30px;
 padding-right: 10px;
}
.list3title1 {
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 26px;
 line-height: 28px;
 font-weight: normal;
 color: #4e4134;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.list3title2 {
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 20px;
 line-height: 22px;
 font-weight: normal;
 color: #adadad;
 margin-bottom: 6px;
}
.list3title3 {
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 15px;
 line-height: 20px;
 font-weight: normal;
 color: #c6c6c6;
 margin-bottom: 8px;
}
/*------------chef------------*/
.title3 {
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 24px;
 line-height: 26px;
 font-weight: normal;
 color: #adadad;
 margin-bottom: 17px;
}
.chef figure {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 float: left;
 margin-right: 15px;
}
.chef figure img {
 width: 100%;
}
.chef .m_bot1 {
 margin-bottom: 14px;
}
/*--------list2--------*/
.list2 {
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
 margin: 6px 0 0 0;
 padding: 0;
}
.list2 li {
 overflow: hidden;
 list-style: none;
 padding: 0 0 0 23px;
 margin: 0 0 7px 0;
 background: url("../images/arrowsmal2.png") 0 5px no-repeat;
}
.list2 li:first-child {
 overflow: hidden;
 padding: 0 0 0 23px;
 margin: 0 0 8px 0;
}
.list2 > li {
 -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease;
 transition: all 0.1s ease;
}
.list2 > li > a {
 float: left;
 display: block;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 12px;
 line-height: 20px;
 font-weight: normal;
 color: #474848;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease;
 transition: all 0.1s ease;
}
.list2 > li > a:hover {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #eb5368;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease;
 transition: all 0.1s ease;
}
.locations .title4 {
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 19px;
 line-height: 26px;
 font-weight: normal;
 color: #adadad;
}
.locations figure {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 float: none;
 margin-bottom: 4px;
}
hr.line1 {
 outline: none;
 border: none;
 background: #e7decf;
 height: 1px;
 width: 100%;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 27px 0 33px;
}
.title5 {
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 19px;
 line-height: 26px;
 font-weight: normal;
 color: #797979;
 margin-bottom: 25px;
}
hr.line2 {
 outline: none;
 border: none;
 background: #dbdbdb;
 height: 1px;
 width: 100%;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 2px 0 27px;
}

.isotope, .isotope .isotope-item {
 -webkit-transition-duration: 0.8s;
 -moz-transition-duration: 0.8s;
 -ms-transition-duration: 0.8s;
 -o-transition-duration: 0.8s;
 transition-duration: 0.8s;
}
.isotope {
 -webkit-transition-property: height, width;
 -moz-transition-property: height, width;
 -ms-transition-property: height, width;
 -o-transition-property: height, width;
 transition-property: height, width;
}
.isotope .isotope-item {
 overflow: visible;
 -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform, opacity;
 -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform, opacity;
 -ms-transition-property: -ms-transform, opacity;
 -o-transition-property: top, left, opacity;
 transition-property: transform, opacity;
}
.isotope.no-transition, .isotope.no-transition .isotope-item, .isotope .isotope-item.no-transition {
 -webkit-transition-duration: 0s;
 -moz-transition-duration: 0s;
 -ms-transition-duration: 0s;
 -o-transition-duration: 0s;
 transition-duration: 0s;
}
.isotope.infinite-scrolling {
 -webkit-transition: none;
 -moz-transition: none;
 -ms-transition: none;
 -o-transition: none;
 transition: none;
}
.pad_bot3 {
 padding-bottom: 42px;
}
#container {
 margin-left: 0;
}
.containerExtra {
 margin-left: -30px;
}
.element {
 width: 270px;
 height: auto !important;
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 color: #222;
 border: none;
 margin: 0 !important;
 padding: 0 0 38px 30px;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
#filters.pagination li a.selected {
 color: #797979;
 background: none !important;
 border: none;
 text-decoration: underline;
}
#filters.pagination li {
 float: left;
}
#filters li {
 display: inline-block;
 margin-right: 26px !important;
}
#options {
 position: relative;
 margin-left: 0;
}
.element > a {
 margin: 0;
 display: block;
 position: relative;
}
.element > a figure {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 margin: 0 0 18px;
 padding: 0;
}
.element > a figure img {
 width: 100%;
}
.element > a span {
 position: relative;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 12px;
 line-height: 20px;
 color: #797979;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.element span {
 position: relative;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 12px;
 line-height: 20px;
 color: #797979;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.description {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
}
#filters {
 position: relative;
}
#filters li {
 display: inline-block;
 margin-right: 20px;
}
#filters li a {
 padding: 0;
 background: none;
 border: none;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 12px;
 line-height: 20px;
 color: #797979;
 margin: 0;
 text-decoration: none;
}
#filters li a:hover {
 background: none;
 border: none;
 text-decoration: none;
}
#options .pagination {
 margin: 1px 0 30px 0;
}
/*--------links------------*/
.btn-link4 {
 color: #474848;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease;
 transition: all 0.1s ease;
}
.btn-link4:hover {
 color: #eb5368;
 text-decoration: none;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease;
 transition: all 0.1s ease;
}
.pad_bot2 {
 padding-bottom: 43px;
}
.links p {
 margin-bottom: 28px;
}
.privacy_page h2 {
 padding-bottom: 42px;
}
.privacy_page p {
 margin-bottom: 22px;
}
.privacy_page .m_bot4 {
 margin-bottom: 27px;
}
.privacy_page a {
 color: #adadad;
}
.privacy_page a:hover {
 color: #eb5368;
}
.smalllogo2 {
 position: relative;
 top: 5px;
}
@media (min-width: 1220px) {
.chef figure {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 float: left;
 margin-right: 31px;
}
.list3 li figure {
 margin-right: 53px;
}
.list3 li .info1 {
 overflow: hidden;
 margin-top: 46px;
}
.box2 figure img {
 height: 270px;
}
.container {
 padding: 0;
}
}
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {

.box1,  .box2,  .box3 {
 float: none;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto 25px;
}
.box1 figure,  .box2 figure,  .box3 figure {
 width: 100%;
}
.box1 figure img,  .box2 figure img,  .box3 figure img {
 width: 100%;
}
.box2 figure img {
 height: auto;
}
.listbox1 {
 padding-right: 15px;
}
.listbox2 {
 padding-right: 15px;
 padding-left: 15px;
}
.listbox3 {
 padding-left: 15px;
}
.list1 {
 text-align: center;
}
.sf-menu {
 display: none !important;
}
.select-menu {
 display: block !important;
 color: #ffffff;
 border: 1px solid #343434;
 background: #343434 !important;
 -webkit-box-shadow: none;
 box-shadow: none;
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 5px;
}
.select-menu option {
 padding: 0;
}
}
/**************************************************/

@media (max-width: 480px) {
.list3 li figure {
 float: none;
 width: 100%;
 margin-right: 0;
}
.list3 li .info1 {
 padding: 20px;
 overflow: hidden;
 margin-top: 20px;
}
}
@media (max-width: 360px) {
.chef figure {
 padding: 0;
 float: none;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<header id="header">
      <div class="menuheader">
          <div class="container">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top tm_navbar negro" role="navigation">
                <ul class="nav sf-menu">
                  <li id='logo'></li><!-- li con id Logo relacionado al css -->
                  <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Casa</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="index.html">Sobre mi</a></li>
                  <li><a href="index-2.html">Guisos</a></li>
                  <li><a target="_blank" href="#">Postres</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
          </div>
      </div>
</header>
<div id="content">
    <div class="slider">
        <div class="camera_wrap">
          <div data-src="http://i64.tinypic.com/2qdmuis.jpg"></div>
          <div data-src="http://i64.tinypic.com/2qdmuis.jpg"></div>
          <div data-src="http://i64.tinypic.com/2qdmuis.jpg"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row_1">
        <div class="container">
            <p class="title1">Aprendamos a cocinar</p>
            <p class="title2">Sencillamente.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row_2">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <ul class="list1">
                    <li class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 listbox1">
                        <div class="box1">
                            <a href="#">
                                <figure><img src="http://i64.tinypic.com/2qdmuis.jpg" alt=""></figure>
                                <p>Guisos</p>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 listbox2">
                        <div class="box2">
                            <a href="galeri_vallas.html">
                                <p>VAsado</p>
                                <figure><img src="images/vallas_img/vallas9.jpg" height="500 px" alt=""></figure>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 listbox3">
                        <div class="box3">
                            <a href="galeri_podas.html">
                                <figure><img src="http://i64.tinypic.com/2qdmuis.jpg"  alt=""></figure>
                                <p>Postres</p>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row_3">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <ul class="list3">
                    <li class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                        <div class="box4">
                            <figure><img src="images/forestal_img/fores13.jpg" alt=""></figure>
                            <div class="info1 maxheight">
                                <p class="list3title1">Guiso</p>                                  
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                        <div class="box4">
                            <figure><img src="http://i64.tinypic.com/2qdmuis.jpg" alt=""></figure>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                        <div class="box4">
                            <figure><img src="http://i64.tinypic.com/2qdmuis.jpg" alt=""></figure>
                    </li>
                    <li class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                        <div class="box4">
                            <figure><img src="http://i64.tinypic.com/2qdmuis.jpg" alt=""></figure>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```